# How to securely provide a database password to the application?

Tags: database, security

I have inherited an application that has fairly well obfuscated, but still hard coded database password inside. The connection with that database is made using a certain database user and this password. The application users are authenticated against a user table in this database. Changing this behavior is outside the scope of my responsibility. Now the customer wants to regain the power over this database user password. He wants to change it himself. How do I go about it? I have few ideas but I would like to know whats is the best way to provide that password securely to my application?

Comment: There is no best way to do this.  Other than connect to the db using your domain creds and control access with configured users/groups.  Hard coding a password can never be truly secure.

Comment: is it a web/server side application or it runs on a client's hardware (like phone)?